# Replace a word with another in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

I want to change all of the words in a text who matches a certain word  with another one in bourne shell. For example:

```
hello sara, my name is sara too.
```

becomes:

```
hello mary, my name is mary too.
```

Can anybody help me?
I know that grep find similar words but I want to replace them with other word.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pure bash way:

```
before='hello sara , my name is sara too .'
after="${before//sara/mary}"
echo "$after"
```

OR using sed:

```
after=$(sed 's/sara/mary/g' <<< "$before")
echo "$after"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello mary , my name is mary too .
```

Comment: The input string would better be named something other than `s`, to avoid confusion in `${s//sara/mary}` and `'s/sara/mary/g'`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, but how could you print $after in the sed syntax if it is not defined?

Comment: Use `after=$(sed 's/sara/mary/g' <<< "$before")`

Answer (score 10):

You can use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for that:

```
$ sed s/sara/mary/g <<< 'hello sara , my name is sara too .'
hello mary , my name is mary too .
```

Or if you want to change a file in place:

```
$ cat FILE
hello sara , my name is sara too .
$ sed -i s/sara/mary/g FILE
$ cat FILE
hello mary , my name is mary too .
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use sed:

```
# sed 's/sara/mary/g' FILENAME
```

will output the results.  The s/// construct means search and replace using regular expressions.  The 'g' at the end means "every instance" (not just the first).

You can also use perl and edit the file in place:

```
# perl -p -i -e 's/sara/mary/g;' FILENAME
```

Comment: sed can also do in-place-modification.

Answer (score 1):

Or `awk`

```
awk '{gsub("sara","mary")}1' <<< "hello sara, my name is sara too."
```