# How to Replace text in the output from a Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, replace

I have a script I run and this is a sample output:

```
OK           J:        \\har-fs01\dept
OK           K:        \\erl-tbafs01.tbamerica.com\share 
OK           L:        \\erl-tbafs01\users\dfeist 
OK           N:        \\erl-tbafs01.tbamerica.com\scanneddata 
OK           S:        \\nov-fs02\share
```

I am trying to replace OK with Net Send and I am having no luck.

I have looked at other code and tried Google as well as here and all of the examples are close but even with modding, I cannot get anything to work.

Comment: There is no programming language listed, but what did you try? Why not just replace OK with Net Send using a string function is that is available?

Comment: I am writing a batch script. Powershell is disabled in my environment.

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142131/replace-a-word-with-another-in-bash

Comment: Thank you for the link but it is a different language. Im using regular old batch.

Comment: Ah I am sorry, I misread batch for bash. Can you update the question with what you have tried, and add the right batch tag?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (My.txt) do (echo Net Use   %%a) >> c:\temp\output.txt

This replaced the text with what I needed and I got the requested results

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).